# Restriction for not allowing same email and password in the database for my signup form

Tags: codeigniter

i want to make a restriction in my signup form which the user cant signup with the already exists email and password..

in my controller:
i already make a rules or callback

```
  array(
     'field'   => 'txt_email', 
     'label'   => 'Email', 
     'rules'   => 'required|valid_email|callback_check_if_valid_email|trim',
                 ),
```

check_if_valid:

```
public function check_if_valid_email()
{
            $where  = array('email'      =>$this->input->post('txt_email'),'password'   =>$this->input->post('txt_password'));

            $this->load->model('database_model');            
            if ($user = $this->database_model->validate_user('user', $where))
            {
               foreach ($user as $row) {
                    $checkemail = $row->email;
                    $checkpassword = $row->password;
                } 

                if ($checkemail == $this->input->post('txt_email')){
                    $this->form_validation->set_message('check_if_valid_email', 'Email already existed!');
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {   
                    if ($checkpassword = $this->input->post('txt_password'))
                    {
                        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_if_valid_email', 'Email already exists!');
                        return false;
                    }
                   else
                    {
                        return true;
                    }

                }
            }
 }
```

in my model:

```
public function validate_user($table, $where) 
{
  $this->db->where($where);
  $query = $this->db->get($table);
  if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
  {
      return $query->result();
  }
  else 
  {
      return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeIgniter's Form Validation library comes with the rule you're looking for, called: `is_unique`

http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#rule-reference

Your validation rules will look like this;

```
required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]|trim
```

All you have to set it the table and column you want to be unique (users.email).

Hope this helps.